# Displaying data inside graphic element, ellipse

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a business condition where I need to highlight a data (number value) value by drawing an ellipse around the data.

The logic is something like

```
if y < X
    Display data highlighted with an ellipse.
else
    Display data
```

Eg:

[image]

I'm using JRBeanCollectionDataSource as the data source and `<jr:table>` for formatting the report.

How can I print the  value inside an ellipse?

```
<jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
    <textField>
        <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="19" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a457d366-5e92-4588-be11-182d164a8db3">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!($F{country}.isEmpty())]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
    </textField>
</jr:detailCell>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put the ellipse before the text element

[image: Ellipse before text]

OR

make the ellipse transparent

[image: Transparent ellipse]

Comment: Thank you @Gustavo for the pointer. Can you please share the jrxml excerpt in any way? Since I'm using the eclipse plugin I'm seeing a bit differently.